# Translate multiple characters in string to the other character at once?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I want to list surnames of my employees, but with changed K Q S letters to X. How can I do it in one go? So far I managed to change one letter at the time

```
SELECT TRANSLATE (surname, 'K', 'X')
FROM employees;
```

But how can I change the rest of the latters (Q, S) to X as well?

Answer (score 3):

Just include them in the arguments:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(surname, 'KQS', 'XXX')
FROM employees;
```

There needs to be an `'X'` for each letter in the second argument.

Comment: Oooh i see, i tried to do this like this but i used only one X instead of XXX, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (surname, 'K|Q|S', 'X')
FROM employees;
```

Comment: This works, but translate will be faster. Regexp is best used when non-regexp solutions don't exist or are too complicated (and therefore prone to bugs and hard to maintain)